# Expected value of a random variable - probability of having a girl and a boy

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

```
Givens:
Lindsay and Simon have a child that is a boy with probability 1/2
Lindsay and Simon have a child that is a girl with probability 1/2
Lindsay and Simon stop having children as soon as they have a girl

Random variables: B= the number of boys that Lindsay and Simon have
                  G=the number of girls that Lindsay and Simon have

Required:  E(B),E(G)
```

I have trouble solving this problem. any help on how to start/solve tis question would be appreciated

Comment: What've you tried out so far?

Answer (score 0):

Every outcome (i.e. sequence of children) has exactly $1$ girl, so $P(G=1) = 1$ and we have
$$E(G) = 1\cdot P(G=1) = 1.$$
Now to calculate $E(B)$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(B=n) &=& P(\underbrace{bb\cdots b}_{n\text{ times}}\,g) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} \\
&& \\
\therefore E(B) &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty{nP(B=n)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty{n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

This sum can be evaluated with a little calculus. For $0 \lt x \lt 1$:

$$\dfrac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n}.$$

Differentiating both sides:

$$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{nx^{n-1}}.$$

Making use of this, we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(B) &=& \dfrac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty{n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{4} \dfrac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^2} \\
&=& 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Alternative method**: a shorter method uses the [Law of Total Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Conditioning on the gender of the first child, denoted by $b$ and $g$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(B) &=& E(B \mid g)P(g) + E(B \mid b)P(b) \\
&=& 0\cdot \frac{1}{2} + (1 + E(B))\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2}E(B) &=& \frac{1}{2} \\
E(B) &=& 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

The reasoning at line $2$ is that given the first child is a girl, it is certain that there will be $0$ boys. If the first child is a boy we have $1$ boy and are then in the same situation as at the start, so that $E(B \mid b) = 1 + E(B)$.

Comment: So the expected value of the number of girls and the expected value of the number of boys are equal? so E(G)=E(B)=1?

Comment: Yes. Obvious for the girls but not for for the boys. Not to me anyway. :-)